# Implicit differentiation concept

Tags: calculus

the problem is $ x^2=(x+y)/(x-y)$

If I start the problem by doing implicit differentiation on both sides I get a different answer than if I first cross multiply and start with $   x^3-x^2y=x+y $.
 ***Is there any mathematical reason that the two methods would not yield the same result?***  With cross multiplication there is a $3x^2$ term which does not appear in the final answer if you start with implicit differentiation of both sides.

Comment: They should not be different. Could you add some detail? How are you computing the implicit differentiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are *not* different.

Let $$z(x,y)= x^2 - (x+y)/(x−y)=0 \tag{1}$$

Then we get $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial z}{ \partial x}}{\frac{\partial z}{ \partial y}}= 
\frac{x\,{{y}^{2}}+\left( 1-2{{x}^{2}}\right) y+{{x}^{3}}}{x} \tag{2}
$$

Let $$w(x,y)= x^3 − x^2y - x-y=0 \tag{3}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial w}{ \partial x}}{\frac{\partial w}{ \partial y}}=-\frac{2xy-3{{x}^{2}}+1}{{{x}^{2}}+1}  \tag{4}$$

Now, expressions $(2)$ and $(4)$ might seem different, but you must remember that $x,y$ are not free, the restrictions $(1)$ or $(3)$ apply. In this case we can isolate $y=(x^3-x)/(x^2+1)$, and replacing we can check that both $(2)$ and $(4)$ are equal:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{{{x}^{4}}+4{{x}^{2}}-1}{{{x}^{4}}+2{{x}^{2}}+1}$$

Comment: I fixed the partial derivatives.

Comment: It should be noted that we can put $x=0$ into $(4)$ but not $(2)$. If we check the conditions of using implicit function theorem again, with $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{-2x}{(x-y)^2}$, we can see that we may have to avoid doing implicit differentiation at $x=0$. And indeed we have to, because there is no $y$ satisfying $z(0,y)=0$. So by transforming the problem $z=0$ into $w=0$, we have actually introduced one extra point $(x,y)=(0,0)$ as a solution.

Other than this singularity point, the derivatives $(2)$ and $(4)$ are equal just fine.

Comment: Thank you for this.  It was not making sense that by simple legal manipulation of the equation I could get different results. Now I see.